# iOS Swift: How to resolve Reciever type 'DatabaseManager' for instance message is a forward declaration?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, compiler-errors

I am using Swift and Objective C code side by side. I recently change my singleton Objective C class from

```
 - (id)init {
  if (self = [super init]) {
    [self initSharedData];
  }
  return self;
}

+ (SharedData *)sharedData {
  static dispatch_once_t onceToken = 0;
  dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{ g_sharedInfo = [[SharedData alloc] init]; });
  return g_sharedInfo;
}

- (void)initSharedData {
  self.databaseManager = [[DatabaseManager alloc] init];
}
```

to

```
required override init()
{
    super.init()

    self.initSharedData()

}


class var sharedData : SharedData {
    struct Singleton {
        static let instance = SharedData()
    }

    return Singleton.instance
}


func initSharedData(){

    self.databaseManager = DatabaseManager()

}
```

As you can tell, I make an instance of an object out of databasemanager and user so I can use it throughout my App.

However, ever since I replace the Objective C singleton class with the Swift singleton class I start getting the follow error in my other Objective C classes throughout my App. How do I resolve this issue appropriately? I don't believe I should have to import databasemanager class in my objective c classes to resolve the issue.

> 'Reciever type 'DatabaseManager' for instance message is a forward
>   declaration '

Comment: Try declaring your `databaseManager` property as ’private`

Answer (score 0):

> I don't believe I should have to import databasemanager class in my objective c classes to resolve the issue.

But you do have to import DatabaseManager to resolve the issue. Forward declarations are just a way to tell the compiler that `DatabaseManager` is a class, and not - say - a function or a constant.

Comment: How come I didn't have to do this when I was using my Objective C code, but now I have to with my swift code?

Comment: @WilliamAlex I don't know, but if the compiler tells you that a forward declaration is not enough, a forward declaration is not enough. There is just no point in arguing with the compiler. If it cannot see the interface of a class (for whatever reason, wether it is a bug in the compiler or not), you get this error message.